# Wordpress: "wp-admin-canonical" gets wrong URL, causing links inside wp-admin to use root instead of sub-directory

Tags: php, wordpress, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I've come across a weird problem where something with the URL settings is causing only /wp-admin/ to break inner links.

To elaborate; I am moving an installation from `blog.example.com` to `example.com/folder/blog`.

After changing the Wordpress `siteurl` to the new one, the front-end of the blog works perfectly fine as expected. **After** logging in to wp-admin at `example.com/folder/blog/wp-admin`; the URL in the browser changes to `example.com/wp-admin` and so do all the internal links in the admin panel.

Hence, clicking on any of the link doesn't work. However, if I manually add `/folder/blog/` to the link; the page loads fine except the URL again changes back to root level.

I have identified this is happening through Javascript. Disabling Javascipt then means the page loads fine. Looking at the page markup, I found the following lines:

```
<link id="wp-admin-canonical" rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/wp-admin/" />
<script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, document.getElementById( 'wp-admin-canonical' ).href + window.location.hash );
    }
</script>
```

If the value in the canonical was correct, it should have been `http://example.com/folder/blog/wp-admin/`

I have never encountered this before. Am I missing any reference I should be changing?

The server is using a ProxyPass; perhaps something missing with that?